# CMake - How to handle dependencies of imported library targets with TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

In my project I rely on some third party shared library named `foo`.

`foo` itself is relying on some other third party dll (let's call it `bar.dll`), which is however neither used by my project nor exposed in the headers of `foo`.

The `foo` target is created and linked to my project as follows

```
add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${foo_dll_path}"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB   "${foo_lib_path}"
)

target_link_libraries(my_project PUBLIC foo)
```

Later on a post build event is triggered to create hard links to all dependent 3rd party libraries via `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:my_project>` generator expression.

How can `bar.dll` be introduced in this setup to be visible in `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:my_project>`?

So far I tried to add `bar.dll` as yet another imported target via `add_library(bar UNKNOWN IMPORTED)` and `add_library(bar SHARED IMPORTED)` and setting `IMPORTED_LOCATION` on `bar` accordingly, which however does create linker errors.
Example:

```
add_library(bar UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(bar PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${bar_dll_path}"
)
target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE bar)
```

In case of `UNKNOWN` the linker will use `bar.dll` as linker input, which of course fails, in case of `SHARED IMPORTED` CMake demands that `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` is set, but neither do I have the import library for `bar.dll` nor do I want to link `my_project` against it.

Any other suggestions how to deal with this?

Comment: Does declaring bar as `MODULE`  or plugin
 (i.e., `add_library(bar MODULE IMPORTED)`) helps to solve the issue? See [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.23/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html?highlight=target_runtime_dlls#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS) for `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS`.

Comment: @vre: ah, I did not try `MODULE`. Unfortunately this still causes a linker error because the value set in `IMPORTED_LOCATION` gets passed on to the linker as input

Comment: And does adding a simple dependency to the imported bar module target via `add_dependencies(foo bar)` instead of `target_link_libraries` work?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately in that case `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:>` does not contain the `bar.dll`. As it turns out there is already an [open issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22993) in kitware's gitlab for this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there seems to be [no proper solution to this issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22993) I came up with a (possibly fragile) workaround involving a meta target:

```
# same as before
add_library(foo_real SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(foo_real PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${foo_dll_path}"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB   "${foo_lib_path}"
)

# add SHARED IMPORTED target with the importlib pointing to foo_reals importlib location
add_library(bar SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(bar PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${bar_dll_path}"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB   "${foo_lib_path}" # same lib path as for imported target foo
)

# add meta target to combine both
add_library(foo INTERFACE IMPORTED)
target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE foo_real bar)

# finally link the meta target to the final project
target_link_libraries(my_project PUBLIC foo)
```

This workaround will cause CMake to generate a build script passing `foo.lib` multiple times to the linker which does not seem to cause problems with the current MSVC Toolset. Also `bar.dll` will now be part of `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS` as intended.